# Switching windows 10 edition from ROG EDITION to Home

Tags: windows, windows-10

i bought a pc that came with preinstalled windows 10 ROG EDITION V4. Our tech from the company i work pretty much finished setting up the pc except the 'encryption' part because he couldn't get it done.

Is there a way to switch from Modded Windows 10 to geniune Windows 10 without fresh installing the windows? Or is it even possible? Suggestions will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You mean apart from it appears to be loaded with malware, from a quick google… Nuke it from orbit, start over & use a licensed version obtained directly from Microsoft [& legitimately paid for].

Comment: @Tetsujin So there's no way other than fresh installing a licensed version of windows 10?

Comment: It might accept a legitimate license, but that wouldn't get rid of the malware. Nuke it. Only way to be even half sure. See https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit

Answer (score 2):

> i bought a pc that came with preinstalled windows 10 ROG EDITION V4. Our tech from the company i work pretty much finished setting up the pc except the 'encryption' part because he couldn't get it done.

**Hopefully, You are able to get a refund, because your current copy of Windows is not legitimate.**. The only search results for “Windows 10 ROG”, is linked to Windows 10 activation hacks, which only have one purpose and they are certainly not legitimate.

You can assume these hacks have been installed on your machine on your behalf.  It also sounds like you are not even running Windows 10 Professional, which means you will be unable to use BitLocker, and it appears your company requires the use of it.

> Is there a way to switch from Modded Windows 10 to geniune Windows 10 without fresh installing the windows? Or is it even possible? Suggestions will be much appreciated, thanks!

You can use Fresh Start on earlier versions of Windows 10 or Reset on the current version.  Be sure you select the option to keep your existing files.  Both methods will download a legitimate and authenticate ISO directly from Microsoft.

**The only problem you will have is your current copy of Windows 10 isn’t legitimate.**  An activation hack has been used to appear activated.  There are no legitimate uses for an activation hack like that.

The real solution to your problem is to order a authentic copy of Windows 10 Professional on a USB drive.  I strongly recommend ordering it directly from Microsoft.  Once you receive the product, I would perform a full and complete reinstall, making sure nothing from your current installation remains.

**This is of course you cannot trust the integrity of the installation you currently have.**